# C99-style hexadecimal floating-point constants in OCaml

Tags: floating-point, ocaml, floating-point-conversion

In OCaml, how can I parse C99-style floating-point constants (either as literals or inside strings) in hexadecimal, such as `0x1.b000000000000p4`?

It seems that they are not valid literals:

```
# let c = 0x1.b000000000000p4;;
Characters 12-27:
  let c = 0x1.b000000000000p4;;
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound record field b000000000000p4
```

And there seems to be no `Scanf` converter to parse them (e.g. a counterpart to C99's `%a` converter for `printf`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`float_of_string` should be able to parse them:

```
# float_of_string "0x1.199999999999Ap1";;
- : float = 2.2
```

However as Alain Frisch [noted](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6909#c14102) on OCaml's bug tracker the support actually depends on the underlying libc and won't currently work on the MSVC ports.

Comment: Indeed. For literals, I suppose a ppx extension or something similar would be necessary?

Comment: At the moment yes. But there's nothing wrong in opening a feature request on [OCaml's BT](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/).

Comment: Note: starting from 4.03, there are `%h`/`%H` modifiers which are similar to C99's `%a`, and literal floating-point hexadecimal constants are accepted and parsed.